# Html - how to prevent consecutive spaces from being collapsed

Tags: html, formatting

I am using an html template to send emails programatically. I know nothing about html, but I've just learned that it will collapse consecutive white space characters, which ruins my formatting(I am emailing a table of numbers). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use a `<table>` if you have tabular data, it'll work much better. You could also use a `<pre>` or `whitespace:pre-wrap` css but I'm thinking a table would suit your needs much much better.

Comment: The html template is generic, it should support both tabular and non-tabular data. However, I can add something to support always not-collapsing whitespaces, i.e. your second idea. How/where to I add that whitespace:pre-wrap? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `<pre>` tag like so:

```
<pre>
 This is some text   with some extra spacing    and a
 few newlines
 thrown in
 for                                              good
 measure
</pre>
```

Working Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bb3dhyyn/)
and a Good [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) on pre tag.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want consecutive spaces to collapse. Just set CSS property white-space.
e.g.:

```
white-space: pre;

<span style="white-space:pre;">                 </span>
```

Check this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the `&nbsp;` metacharacter to produce a "non-breaking space."   (I used one in-between these two sentences. But I didn't use one here.     Notice how the spacing between these sentences is slightly different, and how the last space is twice as wide because I used two tags?)

Fundamentally, I suggest that you should be using `<table>` tags within your e-mail body, thus identifying the data as "tabular" and giving you a rich array of options *(styles, etc ...)* for formatting it.   It will look *much* better than anything you could do by means of "ASCII Art ..."