# Unable to move the bullet points to the right

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to move the bullet points to the right a little bit.
here is the bullet points that i am trying to move to the right::

```
      {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Plan of care:', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.planOfCare.map(plan => `\n     • ${plan}`), bold: false, margin: [20, 0, 0, 0] },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
```

here is the parent code::

```
// util.pdf.pdf-templates.CriticalCareNurseReport.js

const RIGHT_MARGIN = 20;

export const criticalCareNurseReport = (noteData) => {
    return {
        header: {
            text: 'Critical Care Nurse',
            alignment: 'start',
            bold: true
        },
        content: [
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Date: ', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.date, bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },

            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Patient Name: ', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.patientName, bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Date of birth: ', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.patientDateOfBirth, bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Chief Complaint: ', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.chiefComplaint, bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Records Reviewed: ', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.recordsReview, bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Past medical history:', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.pastMedicalHistory.map(plan => `\n• ${plan}`), bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },

            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Social history:', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.socialHistory.map(plan => `\n• ${plan}`), bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Family Past Medical History:', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.familyPastMedicalHistory.map(plan => `\n• ${plan}`), bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },

            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Medications:', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.medications.map(plan => `\n• ${plan}`), bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            {
                text: [
                    { text: 'Plan of care:', bold: true },
                    { text: noteData.planOfCare.map(plan => `\n     • ${plan}`), bold: false, margin: [100, 0, 0, 0] },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },
            
            'Thank you for allowing us to advocate on your behalf.',
            {
                text: [
                    { text: `${noteData.user},  ${noteData.advocate}, ${noteData.degree},`, bold: false },
                ],
                margin: [0, 20, 0, 0]
            },

        ],

    };
};
```

I tried to add spaces in the beginning and its not working.
i tried to add margins and its not working either.
here is what the pdf looks like right now::

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html - how to prevent consecutive spaces from being collapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248536/html-how-to-prevent-consecutive-spaces-from-being-collapsed)

Comment: Are you missing some tags on your question? I’ve done a good bit of React dev but not recognizing this type of React where instead of returning JSX you return JavaScript objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  text: [
    { text: "Plan of care:", bold: true },
    {
      ul: noteData.planOfCare.map((plan) => ({
        text: plan,
        margin: [20, 0, 0, 0],
      })),
      bold: false,
    },
  ],
  margin: [0, 20, 0, 0],
};
```

I've used the ul property to create an unordered list for the bullet points.
Each bullet point is now an object with the text and margin properties.

By setting the margin property to [20, 0, 0, 0],
you're adding a left margin of 20 units to each bullet point, effectively moving them to the right.